# How to check an object deserializable in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization, json-deserialization

i wanna check an object Is Deserializable or not? i want to check a string json can be desirializable or not?  For example :

```
if(obj.IsDeserializable()) { var obj1 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<object>(CObject); } else {  //dosomething ...}
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking... You normally have two things: a JSON string and a .NET type (a *class*)... Do you want to know if given both of them, the JSON can be deserialized to the class, or do you want to know if given a *class* it is possible to serialize and deserialize it or what?

Comment: i wanna check an object Is Deserializable or not? i want to check a string json can be desirializable or not? i want to deserialize a JSON string

Comment: A json string is always deserializable, what is the question here?

Comment: Whether you can deserialize a json string to a specific type means either "does the type at all accept data through deserialization" or "will deserializing this json string into it end up crashing". Can you please clarify exactly what you want to know here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. You can check if object is serializable with typeof(T).IsSerializable. What you can do is wrap this in try-catch block and then do operation on object if serialization succeds. JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject() usually always succeds but the casting then does not where JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject() throws an exception if input includes member definitions that are not available on type T.

Comment: Illegal Json will still cause an exception... like: `new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<object>("'Hello");` (missing final `'`)

Comment: That is true I just focused on member definitions.